# Crash Error Help NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, syntax, nsstring

I have some code that looks like this:

```
NSString *_parse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//%@",_user];
NSString *_status = [Parser parse:_parse:@"status"]; //parses the xml
if ([_status isEqualToString:@"1"]) { //error here
}
```

The application crashes when it checks if the strings are equal. However, this works fine when I replace the first line of code with this:

```
    NSString *_parse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//user1"];
```

But that does not use the "user" ivar which I need to be used because the value can be different. The ivar "user" is a NSString that is declared earlier with `[self setUser:@"userX"];` 
What should I do to fix this? Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code that parses the xml:

```
+ (NSString *)dataFilePath:(BOOL)forSave {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hangout.xml"];
            return documentsPath;    
    }
    + (MyViewController *)parse:(NSString *)nodesForPath:(NSString *)elementsForName {

        NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:FALSE];
        NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSError *error;
        GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];
        if (doc == nil) { return nil; }
        MyViewController *view = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSArray *getVersionInfo = [doc nodesForXPath:nodesForPath error:nil];
        for (GDataXMLElement *versionInfo in getVersionInfo) {
            NSArray *elm1 = [versionInfo elementsForName:elementsForName];
            GDataXMLElement *elm2 = (GDataXMLElement *) [elm1 objectAtIndex:0];
                return elm2.stringValue;
        }

        [doc release];
        [xmlData release];
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error message you get when the app crashes and the code that sets the `_user` variable.

Comment: Also, the second line of code contains a syntax error.  Please copy & paste the exact code.

Comment: @Jim There is no error in the console when it crashes. I know it is the "isEqualToString" because when I take it out, the app works fine.

Comment: When you say that the `_user` ivar is "declared earlier", is that in a different method?  Is your property set to retain, copy, or assign?

Comment: @Jim It is declared in the same method. I did this: @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *_user; Should I use retain instead of assign?

Comment: Try [_status isEqual:@"1"] insed of [_status isEqualToString:@"1"] and put a NSLog(@"%@",_status) gefore cheking isEaqual see what the string has inside. Tell me the results maybe i can help.

Comment: @Preston: You usually want `copy` for `NSString` properties, it depends.  Like I said before though, your second line of code contains a syntax error.  That is not the code you are running.  Please post the code you are running.

Comment: Your `parse` method doesn't make sense.  It has a return type of `MyViewController *` but in one `return`, it returns a string and in the last one it returns a view.  Then in the calling code, you are putting the result (which might be a view) into an NSString.

Comment: Jim is right you should use retain or copy for NSString

Comment: @Radu @Jim Thank you both for the help. I got it working by using copy and using isEqual. Also, the second line was exactly as it is my code and there is no syntax error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in your `parse:nodesForPath:elementsForName:` method.  When you find the element you are looking for, it returns an `NSString` (inside the loop).  When you *don't* find the element you are looking for, it exits the loop and returns an instance of `MyViewController`.  Obviously you can't compare a view controller to a string, so that causes the crash.

This is inexplicable.  Why would you ever do that?  It's not used anywhere before you return it.  It makes no sense to have that code in there.  Cut the references to `MyViewController` out completely.  Return `nil` from your `parse:nodesForPath:elementsForName:` method.  Don't return prematurely within the loop without releasing your allocated memory or that memory will leak.  There's another leak in your earlier return too.